# How to return object from tinygo webassembly target

Tags: go, webassembly, tinygo

I am using tinygo to generate a wasm for simple function:

```golang
//export onInput
func onInput() map[string]interface{} {
    return map[string]interface{}{
        "key": 60,
        "remove": 1,
    }
}
```

Then I am using wasm target to build using tinygo, as:

```
tinygo build -o main.wasm -target wasm ./main.go
```

And when I call the method `wasm.exports.onInput()` I am getting a number such as: `102752`

How would I get the JS object as a return value like:

```js
{ key: 60, remove: 1 }

// Or array [60, 1] if possible
```

**Note:**

The tinygo documentation says:

> The WebAssembly target does not return variables directly that cannot be handled by JavaScript (see above about i64, also struct, i64, multiple return values, etc). Instead, they are stored into a pointer passed as the first parameter by the caller.

If that's the cause of the issue, how would I pass the return value as a pointer from javascript?

**Edit**

I wasn’t able to figure out how I would return any of: arrays, strings or maps from a go function. I would settle for any of the above.

Comment: It would also be OK if returning arrays is possible. The `{ key: 60, remove: 1 }` could be returned as `[60, 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [example](https://github.com/tinygo-org/tinygo/blob/138befd8a25d2a5c65e2e740038a8c3a44e95222/src/examples/wasm/slices/wasm.go) at tinygo github you can try something like this:

```
package main

import "syscall/js"

func main() {
    wait := make(chan struct{}, 0)
    js.Global().Set("onInput", js.FuncOf(onInput))
    <-wait
}

// note that there is no export as we registered this function in global
func onInput(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
    return js.ValueOf(map[string]interface{}{
        "key":    60,
        "remove": 1,
    })
}
```

And in your js code use just `onInput`, without `wasmModule.instance.exports` prefix